# Right syntax to use near '%d AND IDX = %d'

Tags: php, sql

I'm getting the following query error.

```
$total = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tsk_users_ticket_infor WHERE ID = %d AND IDX = %d", $user_ID , $id);
```

How would I go about replacing this system, without putting the variables directly in the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use placeholders, like WordPress recommends you need to prepare the statement on the **get_var**

```
$total = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tsk_users_ticket_infor WHERE ID = %d AND IDX = %d", $user_ID , $id));
```

An insecure and **not recomended** way would be to use the variables in the string

```
$total = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tsk_users_ticket_infor WHERE ID = $user_ID AND IDX = $id");
```